# Click handler for element with highest z-index only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

In a page I'm creating there are some `WebGrid` components serving as master grids, and on clicking a row, a details area is shown. Now every row shall also have a delete button, so that clicking this button, the row is deleted.

Now because I have a click handler for `#myGrid tbody tr`, and the button (which is actually just an image) is inside the `tr`, both click handlers are executed when I click on the button. What can I do to prevent this and just execute the click handler for the button, that is, for the "top" element?

[Here is a jsFiddle roughly demonstrating what I'm currently doing](http://jsfiddle.net/nbvdw0q1/2/)

Is there an elegant way to do this, or is there maybe an alternative to what I'm currently doing?

For reference, here's some even shorter sample code. HTML:

```
<table id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="someImage.png" class="delete-button" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#tbl tr").click(function () {
    alert("row click");
  });
  $(".delete-button").click(function () {
    alert("delete-button click");
  });
})
```

Comment: Please include your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `stopPropagation`

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$(".delete-button").click(function (e) {
    //                              ^
    alert("delete-button click");
    e.stopPropagation();
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/nbvdw0q1/3/

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to stop the propagation of the click event of the elements containing the button:

```
$(".delete-button").click(function (event) {
    alert("delete-button click");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nbvdw0q1/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just capture the parent click then compare the event target against the delete button.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/nbvdw0q1/5/))

```
$("#tbl tr").hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("clickable");
}).click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target) === $('.delete-button')) {
    alert("delete-button click");
  } else {
    alert("row click");
  }
});
```